# Hashing/encrypting an integer to produce an unique integer in the same range

Tags: pseudo-random-permutation, format-preserving

I'm looking for a function or set of functions that can produce a pseudo-random permutation on an input set of arbitrary size.

Given a set of $M$ values in range $0..M-1$, where $M$ is positive integer,
I need a function $I' = F(K,M,I)$, where $I$ is a value in range $0..M-1$, $K$ a key (to be determined) and $I'$ a value in range $0..M-1$.
For each value $I$, there must be only one $I'$ value, and for each $I'$ value, only one $I$ value.

Having the reverse function $I = F'(K,M,I')$ is not strictly needed, but it seems implied by requirement.

So this looks like an encryption function.

If $M$ was $2^{128}$ or $2^{256}$, I could use a block cipher.
If $M$ was a multiple of $256$, I could use a stream cipher (byte oriented).
But $M$ could be any value, without any special properties: it's not required to be odd, even, prime, power of two,...

I'm not aware of such encryption or hash function.
Could you help me to formalize what I need and give me some hints to find an encryption/hash scheme that suits my needs?

I seem to have found what I was looking for: [Format Preserving Encryption (FPE)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption), but I need some help to sort this out.

**EDIT:** In order to be strong, I think it's important the function should not be self-inverse, e.g., given $I' = F(K,M,I)$, $F(K,M,I')$ should not return $I$.

Comment: I realise this is almost certainly unhelpful but $F(K,M,I)=I$ works fine. Could you clarify your question to explain what criteria you have that invalidates this solution?

Comment: If the reverse is not needed this is like a one way function like a hash function and not an encryption function.

Comment: @curious I don't need a reverse, but if I found an encryption function that fullfil my needs, I will use it.

Comment: @user8911 The output should be considered as random in the range. While $F(K,M,I) = I$ for some few $I$ values could be legal, it must be avoided

Comment: @user8911 I want to randomize entries in array, eg. entry order must look random from an eavesdropper.

Comment: Why?if there is a fast hash algorithm, that you can truncate its output?IT's like shooting the fly with a bazooka

Comment: @curious truncating output of a hash function, like $0..2^n  mod  M$ ? There will be collision, and it's unacceptable. Output value must be unique and in range $0..M-1$.

Comment: @ydroneaud: if you are randomizing an array, how big is the array?  There are standard ways to randomize an array (Fisher-Yates) which work just fine if the array isn't too large.

Comment: @poncho 488397168 for example. And I don't want to randomize the array, I want the entries to look randomized. So I want a function that convert array index $I$ to $I'$.

Answer (score 2):

You indeed need Format-Preserving Encryption. It is a pretty easy concept, and [this paper](http://www.cs.ucdavis.edu/~rogaway/papers/subset.pdf) by Black and Rogaway should be readable for non-specialists. The simplest method you should be satisfied with is to use a cycle-walking cipher. Suppose :

- Take $I'\leftarrow E_K(I)$;
- Repeat until $I'\in [0\ldots M-1]$,

where $E_K$ is a conventional cipher with key $K$. However, the block size $n$ of $E$ should only slightly exceed $\log M$, otherwise the procedure would take too long.

If a cipher with such block length is not available, the following construction, known as [Swap-or-not cipher](http://www.cs.ucdavis.edu/~rogaway/papers/shuffle.pdf), should help:

$E_K(X):$

for $i\leftarrow 1$ to $8 \log M$

- $K_i \leftarrow AES_K(i) \pmod{M}$;
- $X' \leftarrow K_i-X \pmod{M}$;
- $X'' \leftarrow \max(X,X')$;
- if ($F_i(K,X'')=1$) then $X \leftarrow X'$.

Here $F_i$ is some key-dependent predicate of $X''$. It must have algebraic degree or higher. For instance, it can be a polynomial of degree 2 over $F_2$, whose coefficients are encryptions of some constants by AES on the key $K$ (similarly to $K_i$).

Comment: The cycle-walking cipher from FPE paper by Black and Rogaway is indeed easy to understand ... but even if it's bounded, it's not a $O(1)$ operation. I will have a look to the Swap-or-not cipher. Thanks